# travel to England

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas, moroccan-citizens

Hi me and my husband are British passport holders who are currently living in Switzerland we have 2 children from Morocco (famille accueil)8 and 7 years old do they need a visa to travel with us to England for 4 days

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they need a Standard Visitor visa. You can check here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that under some conditions the children may be British Citizens - for example if a parent is British 'otherwise than by descent'. They would probably need to be registered as British to visit Britain.

Comment: @DJClayworth as I understand famille accueil, it is a host or foster family, and the children would not qualify until after an adoption.